# Switching to StreetView

Tags: gmlib

I have one problem (first entered as a comment, Aug 2014). The first time I drag pegman onto the map (having moved it using GeoCode away from the default centre), it shows streetview at the default centre (GMMap.RequiredProp.Center.Lat/Lng). Doing it a second time works fine. When I drag pegman, I can very quickly see the correct streetview, then this is overlaid with the wrong one.

My guess is that the streetview layer exists when the program starts, but is not visible. Dragging pegman makes it visible, which then provides the opportunity to close the layer. Dragging pegman a second time creates the layer at the correct position, then makes it visible.

I notice that MegaDemo does the same thing, showing Gaudi's cathedral when the pegman is first dragged onto the map somewhere else.

How do I show the correct position first time?

Regards,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i probably found solution. It is in DoMap script in map.html which is contained in gmmapres.res.

Sinner is line

```
panorama.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(Lat,Lng));
```

when i commented it and recompiled resource (rc.cmd) and then GMLib, Streetview started to work correctly.